# Using for loop to replace values in a matrix but only the last replaced value is kept

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix, replace

```
x_n = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.25)
u_m = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.5)

for x in range(len(x_n)):
    for u in range(len(u_m)):
        zeros_array = np.zeros( (len(x_n), len(u_m)) )
        zeros_array[x,u] = x_n[x] - u_m[u]

zeros_array  

#result
array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ],
      [ 0.  ,  0.  ],
      [ 0.  ,  0.  ],
      [ 0.  ,  0.25]])
```

Only the last replaced value is kept. I want to know how to keep all the replaced values.

Comment: you are initializing a new zeros array every loop

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre]. For example matrixes/arrays have nothing to do with the problem; you could have the same problem with a 1D list.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing a new `zeros_array` on every iteration of the loop, so it's straight-forward that when the loop ends, only the last `zeros_array` value is kept, to solve this, you need to define `zeros_array` once outside the loop and keep updating it inside:

```
x_n = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.25)
u_m = np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.5)

zeros_array = np.zeros((len(x_n), len(u_m)))

for x in range(len(x_n)):
    for u in range(len(u_m)):
        zeros_array[x, u] = x_n[x] - u_m[u]

print(zeros_array)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.   -0.5 ]
 [ 0.25 -0.25]
 [ 0.5   0.  ]
 [ 0.75  0.25]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the initialization of the zeros_array inside the loop so it's doing it every loop

do:

```
zeros_array = np.zeros((len(x_n),len(u_m)))
for x in range(len(x_n)):
    for u in range(len(u_m)):
        zeros_array[x,u] = x_n[x] - u_m[u]
```

output:

```
array([[ 0.  , -0.5 ],
       [ 0.25, -0.25],
       [ 0.5 ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.75,  0.25]])
```